# How do I call method C# Dll method using RegAsm?

Tags: c#, methods, dll, registration, regasm

I created a C# Dll that use "Register for com interop" and I managed to register it using RegAsm:

```
RegAsm.exe -tlb -codebase MathLib.dll
```

After that I got the message:

"Assembly exported to 'C:\Test\MathLib.tlb', and the type library was registered successfully"

How do I call now the methods inside the Dll? For example it has a public function:

```
int Add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

that adds 2 numbers and return the result. How do I call it from the command-line and see the result of the operation?

Thanks very much.

Comment: From the _command line_? You registered a COM object then supposedly you need to consume those types from non .NET code (if it's just the command line then with PowerShell you can directly run it without the COM hassle). AFAIK there isn't any utility to execute arbitrary methods from COM objects using the command line. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, I didn't work with COM objects before but it's seem logic to me that if I do the registration from command-line then also the other operations (like calling methods from that Dll) should be perform from command line. I don't get it, if I want to use my Dll from a non .NET code (for example AutoIt, or Visual Basic) then why can't I do all my operations from there? Why do I have to do the registration from the command-line?

Comment: Unless you're talking about VB6 then VB is a .NET language and you can use assemblies compiled from C# code. Where you register a COM object has nothing to do with how you use it. You register you car insurance online but you won't drive your car from sofa in your living room.

Answer (score -1):

> **How does it work?**
>
> Create a new classlibrary or proceed with an
>   existing one. Then add the UnmanagedExports Nuget package.
>
> This is pretty much all setup that is required.
>
> Now you can write any kind of static method, decorate it with
>   [DllExport] and use it from native code. It works just like DllImport,
>   so you can customize the marshalling of parameters/result with
>   MarshalAsAttribute.
>
> During compilation, my task will modify the IL to add the required
>   exports.

A good example would be the following lines:

```
class Test
{
  [DllExport("Add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public static int Add(int a, int b)
  {
     return a + b;
  } 
}
```

As you know, keep registering your lib with RegAsm. To import your COM function back on another project, you shall Marshall it like a native method, declaring it in your code with the `[DLLImport]` attribute.

References:

[Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports)

**[UnmanagedExports Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports)**

I hope that helped in someway.

Comment: I'm checking the links, thanks. When using this method, will I still have an Exe file and a Dll file in my folder? Or is it merging the Dll inside the Exe during the compilation process so I will have only one Exe file without the Dll?

Comment: So, the article explains how to create a DLL and export some function to Native Code. The function exported to native code can be accessed from any programming language. To use it back on C# you shall Marshall the function. The COM part, from what I saw, you're already doing with RegAsm. You missed to export the method to native code. In fact, you'll get a com DLL on the end.  Not a exe file. This DLL is going to have your exported method Add.